# Не работает OnBecameInvisible

Tags: c#, unity3d

Повесил данный скрипт на объект с вот таким методом:

```
void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    Debug.Log ("Invisible");
}
```

При запуске на камере объект не видно.

Почему данный код не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что окно Scene в Editor'e тоже видит твой объект) + на объекте, где висит скрипт должен быть Renderer любой

Comment: А если я в окне "Game", камера все ровно видит мой объект?

Comment: Это штука срабатывает, когда все камеры игры не видят объект, окно сцены тоже не должно его видеть.